# Using jUnit 4.12 and Hamcrest 1.3, how can I assert a function returns one of two integers?

Tags: java, junit, assert, hamcrest

I'm interested in writing a test that allows me to check whether a function returns one of two values. For example:

```
  @Test
  public void testRandomFunction() {
    assertEquals(
      either(equalTo(2)).or(equalTo(3)),
      RandomFunction(5)
    );
    return;
  }
```

Reading up online I found out about the matchers in hamcrest. The code compiles but when I run the test, it seems the integer 5 is compared to a matcher object instead of integers 2 and 3.

I am open to try something different besides matchers if it makes this easier. Does anyone know how I can do this?

I have also tried the following without success:

```
   @Test
  public void testRandomFunction() {
    Set<Integer> acceptedValues = new HashSet<Integer>();
    acceptedValues.add(2);
    acceptedValues.add(3);

    assertEquals(
      isIn(acceptedValues),
      RandomFunction(5)
    );
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the matchers, you need to use [`assertThat`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Matchers-and-assertthat) instead of `assertEquals`.

```
assertThat(
    "RandomFunction result",
    RandomFunction(5),
    either(equalTo(2)).or(equalTo(3)),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
public void testRandomFunction() {
  int result = randomFunction(5);
  assertTrue(result == 2 || result == 3);
}
```